# add to my nested json doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, object

I am trying to "ADD" a new key "resource1" to my below JSON.
I tried jsonFile["entry"][2] = "resource1" . This worked.

Now i want to add an object with "resourceType", "code", "subject"...... like how it is displayed for "resource" in my json below. How do i achieve this???

Like this --> jsonFile["entry"][2]["resource1"] = {"resourceType" : "Observation"} ?????
Need help here

jsonFile:

```
{
    "resourceType" : "Bundle",
    "type" : "transaction",
    "entry" : [
        {
            "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:patient",
            "resource" : {
                "resourceType" : "Patient",
                "name" : [
                    {
                        "given": ["Lola"],
                        "family": "Tes"
                    }
                        ]
                    },
                "request" : {
                    "method" : "POST",
                    "url" : "Patient"
                }
           },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "resourceType" : "Observation",
                "code" : {
                    "coding" : [
                        {
                            "system": "http://loinc.org",
                            "code": "15074-8",
                            "display": "Glucose [Moles/volume] in Blood"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "type" : "Patient",
                    "reference" : "urn:uuid:patient"
                },
                "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": "5",
                    "unit": "mmol/l",
                    "system": "http://unitofmeasure.org",
                    "code": "mmol/L"
                }
            },
            "request" : {
                "method" : "POST"
            }
         }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to add the property to non existing object.

From your example.

```
jsonFile["entry"][2] = "resource1"
```

this worked because you are adding this to existing property(i.e. jsonFile has entry object which is array. So, it's just simply pushing this to array.
But when you are trying this,

```
jsonFile["entry"][2]["resource1"] = {"resourceType" : "Observation"}
```

it's trying to add property to non extsting object(i.e. jsonFile has entry, but entry has only 0 and 1 position objects in array. So, this will throw error.

To add property at 2nd position, you need to initialise object at that position and then you can add property.
You can do it in following ways,

```
jsonFile["entry"][2] = {}
jsonFile["entry"][2]["resource1"] = {"resourceType" : "Observation"}
```

Or

```
jsonFile["entry"][2] = {"resource1":{"resourceType" : "Observation"}}
```

You can add property to object if and only if that object is exists.